# How to write php include inside div with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to write `<?php include $this->_ script('admin/test.phtml'); ?>` Using jquery within a `<div>` so that it works.

I have already researched and in all the responses recommend using `load("file.php")`, but it does not work in my case, because it is a framework and because of the routes this does not work.

I tried this and it did not work, it does include inside the script instead of doing in div:

```
<script>
  $('.btn-group').on('click', '#btn-edit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $('#myModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static'
    });
    <?php $_GET['id'] = id;?>
    var php = "<?php include $this->_script('admin/teste.phtml') ?>";

    $('.modal-body').html(php);

  });
</script>
```

I tried this code and it also did not work:

```
<script>
  $('.btn-group').on('click', '#btn-edit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $('#myModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static'
    });
    <?php $_GET['id'] = id;?>
    var php = "include $this->_script('admin/teste.phtml')";

    $('.modal-body').html('<?php' + php + '?>');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This will not work I'm afraid. Php is run by the server, before sending your page to the browser. Jquery is executed in the browser, so even if it successfully inserts php, your page is no longer being looked at by the server (which can execute the php), but only by the browser (that can run javascript).

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library which means that it is run client-side, in the browser, and therefore cannot execute PHP which is server-side and run on the server before the page is returned to your browser. You can however use AJAX to request a PHP/HTML page and inject the HTML into the current page

Comment: You can write php with jQuery. 
As it has said here - php is server side while jQuery is client.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get something like this to work is using jQuery to request the page back to the server to get the server processing PHP again.

However, as you've found, loading just the file doesn't work because the file likely included dependencies that are not present.

The way I would solve this problem (I happen to be using WordPress which might change your specific application of my answer) is this:

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.btn-group').on('click', '#btn-edit', function(e) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/", //Or whatever the page you want to use to load this.
        data: {"custom_php_action": "my_special_action"},
        tryCount : 0,
        retryLimit : 3,
        success: function(res){
            jQuery(".modal-body").html(res); //Div for my response
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                this.tryCount++;
                if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                    //try again
                    jQuery.ajax(this);
                    return;
                }            
            return;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

PHP (This is where whatever you are using to build your page will change):

```
function my_custom_controller_function() {
    if ( isset($_POST['custom_php_action']) && $_POST['custom_php_action'] == 'my_special_action' ) { //Tests for our AJAX conditions
        //My Code Here -- Make sure whatever response is echoed and not simply returned.
        //If the function returns a value, then echo it here.

        //Example
        echo 'My Response';
        //Example

        //Example 2
        $data = my_function();
        echo $data;
        //Example 2

        exit(); //Stop the rest of the page from loading.
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'my_custom_controller_function' ); //Control when AJAX kicks in -- we don't want it firing too soon -- or too late.
```

This uses a WordPress action hook that fires after WordPress and plugins are loaded, but before any theme files have been processed (if I understand my hook order correctly). Depending on your framework will depend on how you include the code you are wanting to use.

This is how I have solved dynamic loading of information. Hopefully you can piece together a solution from this example that will work for you since I don't know the class/object combination you are using to locate the document you're trying to load/include and I don't know what the details of the platform you're building upon.

Comment: I'm using Zend. Including in this way does not work, needs to be with php. I do not think there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: I know virtually nothing about Zend, but the principle is the same since WordPress is built on PHP. Get your code to run up to a certain point (preferably before headers are sent), echo what you want output, then exit the script. The jQuery script snippet is not WordPress dependent at all and it works for loading HTML into a div.